# Loading nodes from a specific user and a specific node type

Tags: 7, nodes

I have written this function to do so, but it behave strangly, i am wondering if i have the correct approach

```
function getNodes($type,$userID){
        $where = array();   
        $nodes = array();
        $where[':type'] = $type;
        $where[':uid'] = $userID;
        $result = db_query('SELECT nid FROM {node} WHERE uid = :uid AND type = :type', $where);
        if($result){
            foreach($result as $o){
                $nodes = node_load($o->nid);
            }
        }
    return $nodes;
}
```

Isn't there a drupal API that loads node from the DB by passing it a UID and Node type ?

Comment: In which context are you using this function? If you're building a page or a block with this list of nodes, consider using the [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module.

Comment: @marcvangend thank you for your reply but the view module would not work well in that particular instance. I need the flexibility of getting the node problematically

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In D6 you could pass criteria to [node_load()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_load/6), so you could do

```
 $criteria = array(
   'uid' => $userID,
   'type' => $type,
 );

 $nodes = node_load($criteria);
```

would do the job.

In D7, you don't have this option with node_load as it is just a wrapper for [entity_load](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/entity_load/7). This has a depricated argument which allows you to load nodes in the same way

```
 $criteria = array(
   'uid' => $userID,
   'type' => $type,
 );

 $nodes = entity_load('node',FALSE,$criteria);
```

*note untested*

This may work, but is not guaranteed to.

The approved way to do this in D7 is to use [EntityFieldQuery](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7)

```
  $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
  $entities = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
    ->entityCondition('bundle', $type)
    ->propertyCondition('uid', $userID)
    ->execute();        
  $nodes = node_load_multiple(array_keys($entities['node']));
```

*note also untested*

Answer (score 2):

Technically what you have above should work. There is one small error and that is on this line:

```
// You're always setting the $nodes variable to 
// the last node_load instead of adding to the $node array.
$nodes = $node_load ($o->nid);
```

That being said this can be made better. Here's a better example.

```
function get_user_node_by_type($node_type, $uid){
  $nodes = array();
  $nids = db_query('SELECT nid FROM {node} WHERE uid = :uid AND type = :type', array(':uid' => $uid, ':type' => $node_type))->fetchCol();
  if (!empty($nids)) {
    $nodes = node_load_multiple($nids);    
  }
  return $nodes;
}
```

Also make sure you're using the correct node type name. You have to use the machine name of the node type.